# How to take longitude and latitude in different locations using marker in maps xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am able to get my current location using marker but unable to set the marker into different locations and get the latitude and longitude values using marker.

```cs
public class googlemapsAc : Activity, ILocationListener, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        GoogleMap _map;
        LocationManager locManager;
        TextView loc1, loc2;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mapsActivity);
            loc1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.btn_loc);
            loc1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.btn_loc2);
            locManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
            locManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 0,0, this);
            Location location = locManager.GetLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
            MapFragment mapFrag = (MapFragment)FragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.map);
            mapFrag.GetMapAsync(this);
            if (location != null)
            {
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
                LatLng lat = new LatLng(location.Latitude, location.Longitude);
                 Toast.MakeText(this,"Current location:\nLatitude: " + location.Latitude+ "\n" + "Longitude: " + location.Longitude,ToastLength.Long).Show();
               options.SetPosition(lat);
               p.AddMarker(options);
            }
            else
            {

                Toast.MakeText(this, "Cannot fetch current location!",ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            locManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
        }

        public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
        {

        }

        public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        protected  override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            locManager.RequestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 0,0, this);
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            locManager.RemoveUpdates(this); 
        }
        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            _map = googleMap;
        }
    }
}
```

```axml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_loc" />
 <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/btn_loc2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in this code i am able get the current location in toast message,but when i change the location of marker i didn't get the latitude and longitude values into marker to bind that values to text view.

please help me with getting lat lang values using place markers to bind to Textview

Answer (score 0):

> in this code i am able get the current location in toast message,but when i change the location of marker i didn't get the latitude and longitude values into marker to bind that values to text view.

I didn't see any code about how you change the location of marker, but you can get the latitude and longitude directly from your marker for example like this:

```cs
var latitude = marker.Position.Latitude;
var longitude = marker.Position.Longitude;
```